# Android - Service running in background

Tags: android, service, background

I am quite new to Android programming and I wonder what the best approach would be to keep information updated while the screen is off.

The specific situation is as follows:
- I use a service that extends Service and implements SensorEventListener. 
- I use the accelerometer to check if the user is sitting or standing (onSensorChanged). 
- If the user have been sitting for a specified time the device vibrates and beeps.

The problem is: 
- The service don't update at a frequency that makes the alarm go of i time. Sometimes is is late by a couple of minutes, sometimes it just updates as I turn the device-screen on. 
- The update frequency seems to vary between devices.

My question is: 
- What would be the best approach to solve the problem? Maybe a service isn't the best solution.

My intention is to keep the service running a long time in the background.

Also, I do not want to use a Wake lock because of the battery (which is an important factor in the situation).

// Victor

Comment: I think you can do it by implementing **Broadcast Receivers** to sense accelerometer changes. The same **Broadcast Receivers** must invoke your *Service*, and do what ever it needs to do. But I'm not sure whether it can wake your phone from sleep!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have no problems acquiring the data through the onSensorChange event. Actually the data doesn't go anywhere outside the service and therefore I don't need a broadcaster. 

The calling to the device to vibrate is called within the service.

Maybe the service is running but the vibration and sound-alarm can't be called if device is in "screen of"?

Comment: Well what i intended to say is [here](http://komputercevapver.blogspot.in/2012/08/using-accelerometer-when-screen-off_16.html), I didn't tried it, but if it works your app. will work. Also, since your app. is listening to sensors in stand-by mode, battery will be drained definitely in the process.

Comment: Great link. I will definitely try the solution provided in the blog and see if it works. I can live with the battery drainage if it's from using the sensors. As many times before, the solution in Android is never spot on. What worries me is that it might not work on some devices. I mean, there is never a total coverage for all devices but this one seems a bit assumptionate.

Comment: I've implemented the solution from the blog and it worked at least on my device (HTC desire S). According to the blog it works on "a lot of phones" and I wonder what that might mean. I'm gonna try it on a couple of different devices and see if it's an OK implementation.

Comment: Good to hear from you. :) Keep coding. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned this problem in [this blog](https://komputercevapver.blogspot.com/b/post-preview?token=V0cmXz8BAAA.Lz_oKj4ofuaplGxa_RrEZw.dxu-sGWAvBjUa0Bh_p-beA&postId=546910831053968595&type=POST#!/2012/08/using-accelerometer-when-screen-off_16.html). I had faced this problem like you. I just found a workaround which I write but it does not work every device. Device's policy for sensors depends on manufacturer and manufacturer limits sensors on cheap phones. ( I don't know why but i guess it is about battery usage)

If you want to use sensors you should use wakelock.(If there is a solution with not using wakelocks, i want to try it)